# You have installed latest bundle to the environment but the latest changes what you have made is not seen.What may be the reason for this in cq5

Tags: aem

You have installed latest bundle to the environment but the latest changes what you have made is not seen.What may be the reason for this in cq5

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reason for this could be the the jar file in your apps folder is not getting overridden with the bundle you are trying to install. Try removing the existing bundle first by going to location: /apps/<-your project->/install/<-your bundle->.jar.

Also check if your new files are displayed after installing the bundle by expanding it. If you have created new service component or packages they will be listed under services and exported packages respectively.